# Table data <td> height not changed

Tags: html, css

My table data height is not increasing ? Why ?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name : </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>  
    <td><input type="text" name = "name" height="80"  size="35" /></td>             
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>E-mail : </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name = "name" size="35" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:
http://jsfiddle.net/y9THJ/

Answer (score 2):

height is not an attribute of the [input](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4) element. You may use some CSS for this.

```
  input{
         height:30px;
  }
```

Comment: But in w3schhols.com tutorials (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_height.asp ) they says height is a attribute of td and event worked in their tryItEditor. But not in my code....whats the reason?

Comment: @Nitish, you have the height attribute on the `input` not on the `td` in your code?